# GUI Layout Addition

Tags: swing, user-interface, layout, grid-layout

```
public void testDialog()
    {
        JPanel myPanel =  new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
        grid.gridx=0; //Moves Things across
        grid.gridy=0; //Moves things down
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("ENTER PLAYER NAMES", JLabel.CENTER), grid);
        grid.gridy++;
        JTextField tfNames [] = new JTextField[getNumOfPlayers()];
        //Loops through the number of players, initialising and adding a JLabel and JTextField to the JPanel
        for(int i=0;i < getNumOfPlayers();i++)
        {
            grid.gridx = 0;
            tfNames[i] = new JTextField(10);
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Player " + (i+1), JLabel.CENTER), grid);
            grid.gridx ++;
            myPanel.add(tfNames[i], grid);
            grid.gridy+=1;
        }

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
               "Initial Dialog", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
         //Declaring the array of strings which holds the players name
         playerNames = new String [getNumOfPlayers()];
        //If the 'OK' button is clicked loop through the number of players checking to see if all the JTextFields aren't empty
        //If they are recall this method otherwise store the input player names in the playerName array.
       if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
       {
            for(int i=0;i < getNumOfPlayers();i++)
            {
                if(tfNames[i].getText().equals(""))
                {
                    testDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    playerNames[i] = tfNames[i].getText();
                }
            }
       }
       //If 'Cancel' button is clicked go back to the previous dialog
       else if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
       {
            numPlayersDialog();
       }
       //If 'x' in top right hand corner of the screen is clicked go back to previous dialog
       else
       {
            numPlayersDialog();
       }
    }
```

Trying to style this is causing me some pain now..Want to centre the Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4 JLabels along with their JTextFields. Also Centre the 'Enter Player Names' JLabel which seems to have broke with the changes.

Comment: _GridBagLayout(which I've been trying to avoid)._ words of people who can't use it. It is very flexible and powerful. Yet it requires a little bit of experience to fully understand it (it is about as hard to understand than coding a `<table>` in HTML).

Comment: Done it the GridBagLayout way there now as I couldn't get It working the other way. However, now i'm trying to style it and simple things have stopped working myPanel.add(new JLabel("ENTER PLAYER NAMES", JLabel.CENTER), grid); Ie. That no longer centres the JLabel. Updated the code above so you can see what i've done.

Comment: Added grid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; 
Seems to be something to do with the JTextFields as to why things don't align perfectly in the centre because when I take its size down to 1 from 10 everything gets closer to the centre. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest nested layouts (untested)?

```
-------------------------
|   panel with JLabel   |
-------------------------
| panel with GridLayout |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Just had a go at that, added in: 
JPanel myPanel2 = new JPanel();
myPanel2.add(new JLabel("Enter Player Names"));
myPanel.add(myPanel2);

Just below the initialisation of myPanel. It puts the Label to the top but for some reason the JLabels in the for loop now don't show on the screen but the JTextFields do. Guessing I've done something wrong?

Comment: There should be three panels: `topPanel` with a `GridLayout` of `(2,1)`, which `add`s `labelPanel`, then `add`s `namesTablePanel` which is just like your old panel.